# why does chrome with iis express measure wrong width of page

Tags: html, visual-studio, google-chrome, width, iis-express

i have this simple html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Code: NewYork</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="us">
    <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

when i load it from disk as file everything is correct.
but when i load it with on my local iis express via visual studio, chrome measures a wrong width. when file shows 1100 pixels the iis express file measures 1000 pixels.

window width is 100% same as a use two tabs.

Comment: This is impossible. How a browser renders a page has nothing to do with the server that is is serving it (assuming it does serve it as text/html). Are you sure you're not just missing a DOCTYPE? Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your HTML code, see if it helps, it has to be the first thing.

Comment: i've had strange problems if the html file contains a BOM

Comment: you are right. i would have accepted your answer. i was so stupid an did not see that tab had zoom on -_- so same window showed different pixel width. working on windows wit imac this happens often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see that I accidentally zoomed to about 120%.  The code and everything else is fine.